# My 4K monitor won’t display anything above a resolution of 1280 x 720

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, resolution

I just bought a BenQ 4K 27inch PD2700U monitor and am trying to connect it to my MacBook Pro as an additional screen.

The cable I am using is a DisplayPort to mini display port. It works fine on low resolution, but it won’t display anything above 1300x768 resolution. Everything look so massive on the 4K screen.

What do I need to do to be able to take advantage of higher resolutions?

**The Monitor I bought:**

https://www.amazon.co.uk/BenQ-PD2700U-Monitor-Graphic-Percent/dp/B07GLR6RQF

**Connection I used:**

Displayport to Mini Displayport

**Here is my laptop spec:**

- OS: MacOS Mojave version 10.14
- Macbook Pro: (Retina, Mid 2012)
- Processor: 2.3GHz intel Core i7 Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024
  MB Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB

Here is a screenshot of the spec:
[image]

Please help!

Comment: Go to the Apple menu->About this Mac->Displays. What does it show for your monitor?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I know it can be frustrating when you're attempting to get something accomplished or to solve an issue, however it's vital that you provide us with sufficient details to assist you. As the question is written, we have no idea what MacBook Pro model you're using (and therefore what it's capable of), what settings you have selected in the Displays preference pane, etc. If you can [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/360022/edit) your question to provide more info about your setup and what you've already tried, you'll get better answers. All the best!

Comment: Thanks @Monomeeth .- Sorry, its my first time asking question online. I have amend the post with more info, hope that give you more context.

Comment: your computer cannot display 4k, even on an external monitor. You have thunderbolt ports on your MacBook (not miniDisplayPort), capable of outputting 2560x1600 or lower. I'm assuming that your poor results occurred when using "Default for Display"?  That is usually the safest option, as your computer will detect which resolution to output

Comment: Thanks @MatthewBarclay - if Thunderbolt port limit output to 2560 x 1600 or lower, how do I get the max resolution out of it? like 2560 x 1600. 

Currently if I change the resolution anything above 1280 x 720, the screen just Blank. 

Am I missing some trick? Because it will be a waste to use that monitor at 1280x720 resolution full time.